Is a simple (no function declarations) TypeScript expression automatically a valid JS expression?
TypeScript code requires transpilation into JS.
But are expressions (that is anything that is valid as a right hand side of an assignment) also required to be transpiled?
Obviously a function (with type decorators) can appear as expressions and require transpilation:
const f = ():int => 42;

The return type decoration is TS specific and makes the expression ():int => 42 an invalid JS expression.
My question is more specific toward expressions that return a primitive type. And again, I can embed a TS function into the expression just for the kicks and that is obviously not JS compliant:
const x = (():int => 42)();

If the expression is "plain sequence of operators, literals and variables" without any deviation into function declarations, are there TS extensions that can appear?
PS. there are expressions that require functions, eg. somearray.map((x:int)=>x+1) and the expression is TS not JS, but again this is because the function type decorators come into play. I'm looking for examples that do not involve functions, lambdas and the associated type decoration.

What about s as string and <string>s syntax?

TS does not support int but number!  (():number => 42)(); for TS and (() => 42)(); for JS

What about satisfies?

I'm not sure what kind of answer you're looking for. Typescript is a superset of JavaScript, which means that any expression which valid in JS is also valid in TS. Now if you're asking if there are typescript-only expressions (i.e. ones not found in JS), which are valid in JS, then the answer is obviously "No", because the expression would clearly be outside the union of the two languages. Please clarify your question

This is a blatant repost. Somebody with nearly 300k reputation should know very well that that's not allowed. Fix your original question instead of reposting it.

No
(s as unknown as string).toUpperCase()
n!.toFixed(4)
f<number>()

are all valid expression in TypeScript but invalid for JavaScript.
In general, one does not need a function definition in order to use types.
Moreover, there can be valid TypeScript code that is also valid JavaScript code but the semantics are completely different:


console.log(new Map<String, Number>([]))



See: Why does console.log(new Map<String, Number>([])) log true, true in JavaScript?

Thanks, console.log(new Map<String, Number>([])) is exactly the kind of example I was looking for
